# How can I use Google Hangouts?

Tags: 8.1, google, linked-accounts, chat

My employer moved all of us to Google Apps. Hangouts is really useful to me, because it allows us to have one-on-one chats, a couple of chat rooms for departments and for specific topics and problems.

I've found some Google Talk apps like [Talk.to](https://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/talk-to-messenger/f5722c63-e94c-40b8-bc14-2bc374c18188), [gChat](https://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/gchat/f9da43e4-9bbb-4a6d-842d-629bd6bdc84b) and others, but the Windows Phone Store says "This app is no longer published".

Trying to find out more, I've read about Microsoft adding Google Talk integration to Outlook.com ([link to article](http://www.pcworld.com/article/2038701/outlook-com-adds-google-chat-integration.html)), but this appears to be only for *chats* and not *hangouts* doesn't seem to be the case for my phone.

Is there any way to use Google Hangouts on my Windows Phone 8.1 device?

Comment: Just use IM+ it has support for Google Talk

Comment: I think, Google sabotage g apps. Google keeps me busy with relogining to G+ account through hotmail...

Comment: Nimbuzz offer audio chat to google contacts

Comment: @Dame please make your comment an answer

Answer (score 8):

There is no official Google Hangouts app and may never be due to Google's nearly non-existant support for Windows Phone.

There is an API for developer to use so it's possible, but as you've noticed, no real fully featured 3rd party apps for Hangouts exist (yet?).

There is also no way to use a web version of Hangouts in Internet Explorer on Windows Phone.

Comment: relevant thread here: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!searchin/hangouts/WP8/hangouts/MkWyNZdOpGU/RuScGbJlSXkJ

Answer (score 2):

There is no official Google Hangouts app for Windows Phone.

You can use [IM+](http://www.windowsphone.com/s?appid=7c59963c-ddae-e011-a53c-78e7d1fa76f8) or [Agent + ICQ](http://www.windowsphone.com/s?appid=65e4ff35-7b57-4f74-91d4-8e67817067cc) apps. They are not official or fully functioned but still better than nothing.

See http://www.guidingtech.com/29720/gmail-maps-gtalk-windows-phone/ for review.

See [reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/windowsphone/comments/1j2a8x/why_does_google_refuse_to_work_with_windows_phone/) for discussion.